# Removing an SKSpriteNode from parent is not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

In SpriteKit in xcode, I'm building a game where a player controls a ball(sprite node) and when the ball touches a "ColorOrbChanger" (sprite node) the player takes on that colour and the orb gets removed, but I'm having trouble figuring out why removeFromParent isn't working for this. thanks in advance :)

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var RedOrb = SKSpriteNode()
var OrangeOrb = SKSpriteNode()
var YellowOrb = SKSpriteNode()
var GreenOrb = SKSpriteNode()
var BlueOrb = SKSpriteNode()
var PurpleOrb = SKSpriteNode()

func OrbColorPicker() -> SKSpriteNode {  
let RedOrb = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ColourNodeRed")
RedOrb.color = SKColor.redColor()
RedOrb.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 60)
RedOrb.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - 140, y:     self.frame.height / 2)
RedOrb.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: RedOrb.size)
RedOrb.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.RedOrb
RedOrb.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Player
RedOrb.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
RedOrb.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
RedOrb.runAction(moveAndRemove)
RedOrb.zPosition = 2

/* ^ plus all the other colours Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple, then i added all those into an array that spat out a random colour orb) */

var ColorOrbArray = [RedOrb, OrangeOrb, YellowOrb, GreenOrb, BlueOrb, PurpleOrb]
let countArray = UInt32(ColorOrbArray.count)
let pickOneNode = arc4random_uniform(countArray)
let randomElement = Int(pickOneNode)

if randomElement == 0{
      self.addChild(RedOrb)
}
  if randomElement == 1{
       self.addChild(OrangeOrb)
}
    if randomElement == 2{
          self.addChild(YellowOrb)
}
      if randomElement == 3{
        self.addChild(GreenOrb)
}
        if randomElement == 4{
          self.addChild(BlueOrb)
}
          if randomElement == 5{
            self.addChild(PurpleOrb)
}
return ColorOrbArray[randomElement]



func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Player) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.RedOrb) || (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.RedOrb) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Player){

      let changeColorActionRed = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0)
      Player.runAction(changeColorActionRed)
      RedOrb.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where and when do you create RedOrb variable? Note that you should follow conventions and use camel case notation for variable names. So it should be redOrb

Comment: yea thanks for the tip i do need to start that, its going to mess me up one of these times if it hasn't already haha, so i made all the redOrb variables right under class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {} then i also have an array that holds all the "orb colours" example:

Comment: func OrbColorPicker() -> SKSpriteNode {
  let RedOrb = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ColourNodeRed")
  RedOrb.color = SKColor.redColor()
  RedOrb.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 60)
  RedOrb.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - 140, y: self.frame.height / 2)
RedOrb.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: RedOrb.size)
RedOrb.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.RedOrb
RedOrb.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Player
RedOrb.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
RedOrb.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
RedOrb.runAction(moveAndRemove)
RedOrb.zPosition = 2 }

Comment: Sounds to me like redOrb is not the actual orb being removed

Comment: @Pulse, just update your code in your question instead of posting a garbled mess.

Comment: Just for reference, you could replace all the if statements with a `switch` of `randomElement`

Comment: Are you creating multiple orbs in `OrbColorPicker()` but only adding one to the scene per call? Also, the `RedOrb` instance variable is not the same as the `RedOrb` created in `OrbColorPicker()`.

Comment: @Nik `self.addChild(ColorOrbArray[randomElement])` will work as well.

Comment: @0x141E Yeah. Both work.

Comment: so basically i just wanted to "make" all the colours available for calling, but only pick one at random then only add that one to the right of the scene then with another SKaction i have move it off to the left of the screen but if it collides with the player, the player would change to that orbs colour then the orb would be taken off the scene, but ill try switching some things around here

Comment: The reason the red orb wasn't being removed is because it's a different "RedOrb" than the one that you're referring to in your code.  When you said "let RedOrb = ..." in OrbColorPicker(), you created a new local variable called RedOrb, distinct from your object's RedOrb property, and it is this orb that you added to the scene.  Your object's RedOrb property remained unchanged, and the sprite it referred to was presumably never added to the stage.  So when you later said "remove RedOrb from its parent", it referred to the one that was never added to the stage, not the one that was.